# Error al crear copia de seguridad con mysqldump en php

Tags: php

Estoy tratando de hacer una copia de seguridad de la base de datos desde php.

Este es el codigo que uso:

```
$Copia_Archivo = $RutaDocumentos."/Copias/backup-" . date("d-m-Y") . ".sql.gz";

// comandos a ejecutar
$Comando = "mysqldump --host=".$_SESSION['Servidor']." --user=".$_SESSION['Usuario']." --password=".$_SESSION['Password']." ".$_SESSION['BaseDeDatos']." | gzip > $Copia_Archivo";

// ejecución y salida de éxito o errores
system($Comando,$output);
if ($output == 0) { $Salida = "Copia realizada correctamente"; }
if ($output == 1) { $Salida = "Archivo no encontrado"; }
if ($output == 2) { $Salida = "Archivo de copia corrupto"; }
echo $Salida;
```

Pero me crea el archivo sin nada de contenido.

El servidor es Debian y la version de php que corre es la 7.1.

¿Que puedo tener mal?

Comment: ¿has probado a hacer un `echo` de $Copia_Archivo e intentar ejecutar esa linea desde consola?

Comment: Pues es buena idea @nachfren voy a probar desde la consola.